# Error loading the Web Part in Kentico

Tags: web, kentico

Recently I upgraded a site from Kentico 8.2.4 to Kentico 8.2.5. After the upgrade for some custom Web Parts which used to be displayed well an error message appeared "Error loading the Web Part xxx of type yyy. The blogs on the Kenico site suggested that I make sure the files are in the WebParts folder, as it is usually a common problem for this type error. But it seems the files are all there as is the path in the database. Any suggestions what could have gone wrong and where to look for answers.

Comment: Typically a hotfix will not break any webparts in my experience.  Look in the event log for the full error, this should help resolve your problem.  I'm willing to bet the issue is something more than just a minor hotfix update.

Comment: Well it did! Twice! I rolled back the changes first time and then did the install again, the same issue happened the second time.

Comment: The same problem happened on importing the site (on another server). The message is that it can't load the Web Parts and the files are in the folder where they should be. What else I can look for except if the files are in the same folder as specified in the database. Any property that should be turned on or off?

Comment: Try registering new web part based on those files.

Comment: With the limited info it's hard to troubleshoot the problem fully.  Have you checked the webpart setup in Kentico?  Maybe try setting to a different file and then setting back to the current file.  

Can you tell me if the webpart that is on a page template is using a different webpart layout?  You'd find this in the webpart on the template when you open the configuration of it.  There will be a layout tab at the top.  If it doesn't say "Default" then it's using a custom one.  Make sure there is a full relative URL to the .CS file.

Comment: I was reading through Kentico documentation and came across post mentioning that similar problems can arise when the  macro signatures are broken. Did you have any experience with that? When re-assigning the signatures what would be the old salt signature to use and how do I find it?